# How do I get different instances of Same singleton classes from 2 different jars in java

Tags: java, singleton, classloader

I Have a singleton class which is in 2 different jars. I've both jars in my class path. Now my application is running inside a JVM. I want to get instances of both the singletons. How can we achieve this in java? Is it possible using class loaders?

Comment: Do both classes have the same absolute name?

Comment: Ae they in different packages? If yes, specify the full package name when using them.

Comment: a so called doppelganger singleton

Comment: Then use [UrlClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Both classes are in same package name. Just logic used in methods are different. Rest is exactly same.